# How to use odeint in python using some constraints in between time sequence?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, iteration, odeint

I am trying to solve a set of coupled differential equations in python using odeint. Let's say two time-dependent equations that involve two variables such as

```
dv(t)/dt = -(v(t) - Vr) + delta*exp(v(t) - vth) - w(t)/g
dw(t)/dt = a(v(t) - Vr) - w(t)
```

with reset dynamics
if v(t)>vth , v = Vr, w = w+b
I tried my best but didn't get the desired results because I don't know how to use odeint for some time variable parameter to reset in between sequence of time.

my code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

pi = -60*10**-3 #mv
delta = 2.5*10**-3 #mV
vth = - 52*10**-3 #mV
gl = 25*10**-9 #nS
tau_m = 20*10**-3 #ms
a = 1*10**-9 #nS
tau_w = 600*10**-3 #ms
b = 0.6*10**-9




def Saponati(states, t):
    v, w = states
    v = (-(v - pi) + delta*np.exp((v - vth)/delta) - (w/gl))/tau_m
    w = (a*(v - pi) - w)/tau_w
    print("v", v, w)
    if v>vth:
        v = pi
        w = w+b
        print(v)
    return states

#state0 = [-57, 0]

states0 = [-57, 0.001]
t = np.arange(0.0, 40.0, 0.01)

v = odeint(Saponati, states0, t)

plt.plot(t, states[:,0])
```

Comment: what have you tried so far. Please refer https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html

Comment: can anyone help me in this. I am still did not get answer.

Answer (score 0):

You were plotting wrong type of variable. The list v must be single dimension list.
So by converting v to y you can find the desired results.

I have marked my chages

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

pi = -60*10**-3 #mv
delta = 2.5*10**-3 #mV
vth = - 52*10**-3 #mV
gl = 25*10**-9 #nS
tau_m = 20*10**-3 #ms
a = 1*10**-9 #nS
tau_w = 600*10**-3 #ms
b = 0.6*10**-9

def Saponati(states, t):
    v, w = states
    v = (-(v - pi) + delta*np.exp((v - vth)/delta) - (w/gl))/tau_m
    w = (a*(v - pi) - w)/tau_w
    #print("v", v, w)
    if v>vth:
        v = pi
        w = w+b
        print(v)
    return states

#state0 = [-57, 0]

states0 = [-57, 0.001]
t = np.arange(0.0, 40.0, 0.1)

v = odeint(Saponati, states0, t)

# My change to simplify v list
y = []
for x in v:
    y.append(x[0])

# My change end.
#print(y)

plt.plot(t,y)
plt.show()
```

See attached screenshot.

Note: I have changed the interval of t for simplification purpose. You can change according to your need.
[image]